# How do you hide the subject field of iMessages on OS X?

Tags: mac, messages

Is there a way to hide the subject field of messages which appear in the top right corner of the screen when I receive an iMessage on my computer? I know there is a way to hide it on messages that come to my iPhone. Is there a way to do the same on Mac OS X?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean for sure, but take a look under System Preferences → Notifications as you might find your answer here.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To clarify on what @Macmaniman posted, you'll want to change a setting with your notifications. To do this, go to your Settings app > Notifications (upper right corner) > Messages (in the left-hand column). Uncheck `Show message preview`, which will hide the message previews (or subject fields, as you refer to them).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I actually think he means the actual subject line above the actual message (it splits the input text area in two, see screenshot).

I haven't found this option in iMessage anywhere on Yosemite though...

[image]